# jsPlumb with dragged connections: How to bind click-events on connection?

Tags: javascript, click, connection, bind, jsplumb

I connect endpoints in jsPlumnb via drag and drop. When I try to bind a click-event to the established connection (e.g. to detach it) I get no result with this code:

```
jsPlumb.bind("connection", function (info, originalEvent) {
    alert("connected "+info.sourceId+" and "+info.targetId + " via "+info.connection);
    var connection = info.connection;
    connection.bind("click", function(connection, originalEvent) {
        alert("you clicked on "+connection);
        jsPlumb.detach(connection);
    });    
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

found it: Don't add other click-related listeners, they might consume the event and prevent the bound click-listener to be fired.

The above code works quite well without any other click-listener involved...

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you connect endpoint using drag and drop?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the `click` handler directly on the JS Plumb instance:

```
var plumb = jsPlumb.getInstance();
plumb.bind("click", function(connection, originalEvent) {

    alert("you clicked on " + connection);
    jsPlumb.detach(connection);

});
```